# Abort trap 6 when merging arrays in bottom-up Merge Sort

Tags: c++, arrays, mergesort

I was trying to implement Merge Sort (Bottom-up approach) until a mysterious Abort trap occurs:

```
void botup_mergesort(int *arr, int begin, int end)
{
    for (int merge_sz = 1; merge_sz < (end - begin); merge_sz *= 2)
    {
        for (int par = begin; par < end; par += merge_sz*2)
        {
            const int &sub_begin = par;
            const int &sub_end = std::min(par + merge_sz*2, end);

            if (sub_end - sub_begin <= 1)
            {
                continue;
            }

            const int& m = par + merge_sz;

            const int &merge_size = sub_end - sub_begin;
            int *aux = new int[merge_size];
            int cnt = -1;

            int p1 = sub_begin;
            int p2 = m;
            while (p2 < end && p1 < m && p2 < sub_end)
            {
                if (arr[p1] <= arr[p2])
                    aux[++cnt] = arr[p1++];
                else if (arr[p1] > arr[p2])
                    aux[++cnt] = arr[p2++];
            }

            while (p1 < m)
            {
                aux[++cnt] = arr[p1++];
            }

            while (p2 < sub_end && p2 < end)
            {
                aux[++cnt] = arr[p2++];
            }

            for (int i = sub_begin, m_cnt = 0; i < sub_end; ++i)
            {
                arr[i] = aux[m_cnt++];
            }
            delete[] aux;
        }
    }
}

void sort(int *arr, int begin, int end) { botup_mergesort(arr, begin, end); }

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 5, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 5};
    // int arr2[] = {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 5, 3, 9, 4, 6, 2, 1, 5, 1, 5, 7};
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);
    cout << "Size: " << n << endl;

    sort(arr, 0, n);

    print(arr, n);
    return 0;
}
```

The code works fine for small arrays, i.e `int arr2[]`, but as the array gets bigger, Abort trap comes back.

I tried using the debugger and it returned `SIGABRT` at `delete[] aux;`. I did a little search on the internet and decided to use `std::vector` instead of a dynamic array, and it worked. However, I really desired to know what is wrong behind this code.

My compiler is Apple clang version 11.0.3 on Visual Studio Code.

Thank you for your help! Sorry I've forgetten something, I am a inexperienced college student.

Comment: *I did a little search on the internet and decided to use std::vector instead of a dynamic array, and it worked.* -- It probably only worked by luck.  If you really translated your code to use `std::vector`, you more than likely are witnessing *undefined behavior*.  Take the `std::vector` code you say you produced, and instead of using `[]` to access the elements, use `std::vector::at()`.  Don't be surprised if your `std::vector` version no longer works, but instead outputs a `std::out_of_range` exception.

Comment: `aux[++cnt] = arr[p2++];` -- Also, why are you making the code obtuse and hard to follow?  Using `++` in all of these contorted ways makes the code look suspicious, and at the very least, hard to follow.  There is nothing wrong with just simply breaking up those lines into multiple lines, so it is clear when p2 is added to, and cnt is added to.

Comment: [Lo and behold, just as I predicted](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5970358d0ff4a45d).  Using `at()` shows that you are going out-of-bounds.  Going out-of-bounds is undefined behavior, and can only guarantee to be detected if you use `at()`, or you explicitly check every index being used when you use `[]`, or if your runtime library has debugging features where it will do the check for these conditions.  Otherwise, your code just runs wild with this condition having occurred, giving erratic results.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That used to be considered the correct way to use `++` in C, although I doubt OP is old enough to remember that.  Maybe the teacher still does it....

Comment: You are corrupting the heap. At one point the `aux[++cnt] =` is out of bounds. At your line 33 put an `assert(cnt<merge_size)` and you will see it.

Comment: @Spencer It may be correct, but only write code like that when you know what you're doing, *and* you are sure the index is not going out-of-bounds.  And for the latter, it becomes difficult, if not near impossible to debug the out-of-bounds condition, since the increments are being done in one statement -- that's why it would have been advantageous to break up the line, and check those indices before being used.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  You're absolutely right about the bounds issue; I was just commenting on your comment about the weird use of `++`.   And you're also absolutely right about that, too -- it makes errors harder to spot.

Comment: @OP *However, I really desired to know what is wrong behind this code.* -- Don't know what answer you will be expecting, since the code is broken with or without using `std::vector`.  Best to leave a comment to say "your code goes out-of-bounds" -- how to fix the code is a different story altogether.

Comment: Thank you all for helping me! This is not the first time I encoutered out of bound problems, but everytime I struggled to debug it. Better write cleaner code next time. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following change will fix the error:

```
        const int& m = std::min(par + merge_sz, end);
```

The code could be a bit faster if a one time allocation of a full sized second array was done, and if the direction of merge was changed on each pass, instead of doing a copy back after each merge. The code would need to detect if the number of passes is odd, where the last merge would put data into the second array, where it would need to copy the data back to the first array one time.